When the keyboard is opened, it covers part of the container
When you click on the bottom input field, the keyboard overlaps it
page.add(

    ft.Container(
        ft.Column(
            [
                ft.Text('Welcome', size=30, text_align=ft.TextAlign.CENTER),
                ft.Text('Enter your username or email and password'),
                ft.TextField(label='Login or email'),
                ft.TextField(label='Password', password=True, can_reveal_password=True),
                ft.ElevatedButton('Log in'),
                ft.Divider(),
                ft.TextButton('Forgot password?', height=35),
                ft.TextButton('Register', height=35)
            ],
            horizontal_alignment=ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER
        ),
        expand=True,
        padding=ft.padding.Padding(10, 40, 10, 20)
    )
)

I tried scrolling, but it doesn't work

Have you tried using a SafeArea yet? It should keep keyboards and phone notches out of the way for you
page.add(
    ft.SafeArea(
        content=ft.Container(
            ft.Column(
                [
                    ft.Text('Welcome', size=30, text_align=ft.TextAlign.CENTER),
                    ft.Text('Enter your username or email and password'),
                    ft.TextField(label='Login or email'),
                    ft.TextField(label='Password', password=True, can_reveal_password=True),
                    ft.ElevatedButton('Log in'),
                    ft.Divider(),
                    ft.TextButton('Forgot password?', height=35),
                    ft.TextButton('Register', height=35)
                ],
                horizontal_alignment=ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER
            ),
            expand=True,
            padding=ft.padding.Padding(10, 40, 10, 20)
        )
    )
)

